# Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFBoolean length]

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter

[image]

After upgrading some Flutter packages and the Flutter framework of the application i'm working on i got this error on iOS. On VSCode it just build the application, but didn't got any useful info. On Xcode the application started with a white screen then printed this on console.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As i'm not used to iOS - Swift - Xcode ecosystem took me a while to figure this out, the Xcode logs were a bit confusing to me. After reading issues on GitHub this popped out and had something related with my console message [What should be the domainNetworkPolicy while using flutter in existing iOS App](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/65580)

This made me realize that was something with the Info.plist file.

The problem was the package `flutter_webview_plugin` and with its configuration on iOS. The XML code was wrong after updating.

This is the correct XML, thanks to [vanelizarov](https://github.com/fluttercommunity/flutter_webview_plugin/issues/214#issuecomment-435008034):

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
        <dict>
            <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
            <true/>
            <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoadsInWebContent</key>
            <true/>
            <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
            <dict>
                <key>url.com.br</key>
                <dict>
                    <key>NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
                    <true/>
                    <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
                    <true/>
                </dict>
            </dict>
        </dict>
```